# Doctrine CLI :generate-models-db give me this error Couldn't locate driver named mysql

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine, ubuntu-9.04

Here is my configuration:

Ubuntu 9.04
Apache 2
MySql
Php 5.3.3-0
Zend Framework 1.11.1
Doctrine 1.2

When I try to create my model from database with the doctrine CLI , I get this error Couldn't locate driver named mysql.

I Know My pdo_mysql is active in both php.ini file.
What I Should do.

Thanks .

Comment: are you sure that you had `php-cli` package installed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does [this blog post on the same problem](http://dyihi.blogspot.com/2009/12/symfony-doctrine-couldnt-locate-driver.html) help?

They enable both

```
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

for the CLI.

Comment: I Already follow these instruction and I got the same error. If i go to /etc/ph5/conf.d/ I got : gd.ini mcrypt.ini mysqli.ini mysql.ini pdo.ini pdo_mysqql.ini suhosin.ini

Comment: thats was the answer. Thanks :)